# Modificar conteúdo do wp-login.php

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Olá, estou criando um plugin que altera o layout da tela de login do Wordpress (localizada no *wp-login.php*), porém além de alterar o style da página (o que já consegui), queria poder adicionar elementos HTML na mesma, só que sem editar diretamente o *wp-login.php*.

Tem alguma forma onde consigo redirecionar a leitura do arquivo original para um que eu mesmo criei dentro do plugin?

Agradeço desde já.

Comment: É mais prático encontrar um plug-in que faça isso para você do que tentar fazer isso manualmente...

Comment: @PauloRoberto sim, mas no momento preciso usar esse plugin próprio p/ aplicar em vários sites durante o ano, sem ter que modificar o wp-login.php toda vez que for fazer essa alteração. A maioria dos plugins prontos vem com muitas funcionalidades e outras eu mesmo irei adicionar conforme minha necessidade. Se tiver alguma ideia de como posso fazer, agradeço o feedback.

Comment: Você pode utilizar o [VQMod](https://github.com/vqmod/vqmod/wiki/Integration-with-Other-Platforms) (não testei com o WP) ou criar sua página de login: `meu_login.php`

Answer (score 0):

Uma maneira "simples" de fazer isso, é redirecionando o login para uma página customizada, e lá você faz as modificações que você precisa.

Procura no codex `wp_login_form()`.

Esse [artigo](http://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/how-to-find-your-wordpress-login-url/) também pode te da uma luz

Answer (score 0):

Outra solução seria usar o functions.php do seu child para inserir esses elementos dinamicamente. Exemplo:

```
function my_custom_login() {
    echo '<script>

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {

    // Your code to run since DOM is loaded and ready
    document.getElementById(\'loginform\').insertAdjacentHTML(\'beforebegin\',
        \'<span class="asterisk">*</span>\');

    });

</script>';
}
add_action('login_head', 'my_custom_login');
```